# Googleapis library jquery version

Tags: jquery

I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which enables scrolling of date and time on my home web page. If I change the version number to a higher (later) one such as 3.5.2, the scroll stops working.

I am also using jquery to cause a menu to be included on the same page:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#links_menu").load("MenuOct21.html"); 
});
```

It works with either version. Can someone explain.

Also, this:

```
<script src="../Scripts/Marquee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

does not work with version 2.x.x or higher?

Comment: There is no jQuery version 3.5.2, so if you updated the URL to that version, that's why it's not working. The latest version (at time of this comment) is [3.6.0](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js). If your code still doesn't work with that there a breaking change between v1.x and v3.x has affected the logic. Without seeing how your scroll logic works, we can't help you debug the problem, though.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I got there, but that clears it up.